# JavaScript - What is the best method when creating chainable functions?

Tags: javascript, return, return-value

**EDIT** 
Here is an attempt to make my question simpler.

```
return this.someFunc(); == return { XXX:this.someFunc() };
```

**What do I have to put in for XXX to make this statement true?**

---

I'm trying to create a function that can be chained. Let me write some hypothetical code. (Any syntax errors just ignore, I'm typing this fast and this is just concept code.) Assume that all functions are either defined locally or globally. :)

```
test = function(){
  this.someFunc = function(){
    this.retest = function(){
      //...code
    }
    //...code
  }
  this.someFunc2 = function(){
    //...code
  }
  return this.someFunc();
}
```

This function allows me to chain: `test().retest();` 
But what I want to do is return more than one item.

```
test = function(){
  this.someFunc = function(){
    this.retest = function(){
      //...code
    }
    //...code
  }
  this.someFunc2 = function(){
    //...code
  }
  return { XXX:this.someFunc(), //What do I put for XXX
           next:this };
}
```

I want to do this to access another function that test() offers: `test().next.someFunc2();`

**So my problem is this:** 
I still want to be able to chain like this: `test().retest();` 
 
But I have to do it like this: `test().XXX.retest();` 
In my code, what is the name that I can put instead of XXX to accomplish this? And is this even possible? I have tried `0` and `default` already. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your first function does not let you write `test().retest()` unless "retest" is a global function.

Comment: @Pointy - Sorry. I edited my explanation. It is defined in the code.

Comment: the problem is that `this` will, if you just call `test()`, be a reference to `window`.

Comment: @Pointy - Assuming it wasn't, what would be the default name that I could put in place of XXX?

Comment: How about "someFunc"?  Call it whatever you want. And the value should be a reference to the function, not a call to the function. (Unless "someFunc" itself returns a function.)

Comment: Taking a step back, *why* are you trying to accomplish this?  Perhaps there's a better design.

Comment: @eggyal - I'm sure there are other ways. One example would be to Find and Replace all `test().retest()` with `test().XXX.retest()` in my code. But now I'm curious if there is a default value. I like having a deep understanding of things so I think this will help me get there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make a chainable functions like this:

```
var test = function(){

    var self = {};
    console.log('test called')

    function someFunc() {
        console.log('someFunc')
        return self;
    }

    function someOtherFunc() {
        console.log('someOtherFunc')
        return self;
    }   

    self.someFunc = someFunc;
    self.someOtherFunc = someOtherFunc;
    return self;

}

test().someFunc().someOtherFunc();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You should replace `var self = this` for `var self = {}`. Using `this` in this case taints the global scope. Returning an object created inside the function is better.

Comment: Also, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vapocalypse/2Apca/) for another aproach.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have been new test().someFunc(). By using {} instead of this is safer.

Answer (score 3):

```
function test() {
   // when test() is called as a regular function
   // it's `this` will be `undefined` (in strict mode) or will refer to a global object
   // when test() is called with `new` operator
   // it's `this` will be an instance of `test` object
   if(!(this instanceof test)) {
      // create a new object
      return new test();
   }
   else {
      // this is a `new object` creation              
      console.log('new Test created');
   }
}

// declare functions which will be accessible on test object
test.prototype.someFunc = function() {
    console.log('someFunc');
    return this;
};

test.prototype.someFunc2 = function() {
    console.log('someFunc2');
    return this;
};

// declare a `chaining` function - will create a new `test` object
test.prototype.test = function() {
    return new test(); // new instance will be created
};
```

With this code you are now able to run the following code

```
test().someFunc().someFunc2().test().someFunc().someFunc().test().test()
```

The following string will be written at the console

```
new Test created
someFunc
someFunc2
new Test created
someFunc
someFunc
new Test created
new Test created
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a scope problem -- you can't refer to the **_NAME** "test" in the function, because you don't know, how it's called.

if you do it statically, you just can do:

```
test = function(){

    this.someFunc = function(){ // blaaa
    };

    //...code 
    return { 
        OUTPUT: this.someFunc(), //What do I put for XXX
        test: this
    };
}
```

will result into:

```
test().test().test().test().OUTPUT (or something like this)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I think I understand your question, but I'm not sure (and it's super late at night here, so give me some credit on that). I think you want to have behavior like this:

```
test(); //is ["result1"]
test().retest(); //is ["result1", "result2"]
test().retest().retest(); //is ["result1", "result2", "result3"]
```

You might want to return objects instead of strings, but it's the same general idea. And the code turns out to be pretty simple:

```
var test = (function() {
    var results = ["result1"], 
        i = 1;

    results.retest = (function() {
        results.push("result" + (++i));
        return results;
    });

    return results;
});

test(); //is ["result1"]
test().retest(); //is ["result1", "result2"]
test().retest().retest(); //is ["result1", "result2", "result3"]
```

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but maybe it gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = function(){

  var someFunc = function(){
      //...code
  }

  return {
      someFunc:someFunc,
      next:this
  }
}
```

*EDIT* - Updated to reflect your question update, for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
test = function(){
  this.someFunc = function(){
    this.retest = function(){
      //...code
    }
    //...code
  }
  this.someFunc2 = function(){
    //...code
  }

  var ret = this.somefunc();
  ret.next = this;

  return ret;
}
```

EDIT: Here's a better, functioning, version

```
test = function(){
  var ret;

  var func = function() {
    console.log("test func");
  }

  ret = function(){
    func();
    return ret;
  }

  ret.test = ret;
  ret.next = ret; // You can define an arbitrary number of members here
  ret.XXX = func(); // Like this, and you can still chain it like your question

  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your intention is, but this would be a chainable `Test` function:

```
function Test(){
  Test.retest = Test.retest || function(){console.log('retested'); return Test;}
  return Test;
}
Test().retest().retest().retest().retest();
/* => result
 retested
 retested
 retested 
 retested
*/
// and
log(Test() === Test); //=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your example does not work the way you posted it I suppose you meant following:

```
test = function(){
  this.someFunc = function(){
    this.retest = function(){
      //...code
    }
    //...code
  }
  this.someFunc2 = function(){
    //...code
  }
  return new this.someFunc();
}
```

Mind the **new** in the return.
Now, to still be able to chain your functions you have to return this:

```
return {retest: new this.someFunc().retest, next:this};
```

Doing so will then allow you to call `test().retest();` 
I hope this helps.